# Alert is not working in chrome but its working in firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I write same code for firefox driver its working fine there but its not working in chrome driver.

```
driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/ul/li[3]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
Thread.sleep(100);
alert.dismiss();
```

Comment: @DebanjanB it is not authentication issue actually alert is not finding.

Comment: On this [website](https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/) the locator `//*[@id=\"content\"]/ul/li[3]/a` doesn't identifies any element through `chrome-dev-tools` and the nearest locator is `//*[@id='content']/ul/li[3]/a` which identifies the element with text as **Basic Auth (user and pass: admin)**. Hence I have marked as duplicate. Let me know if I am wrong so I can _ReOpen_ the discussion.

Comment: @DebanjanB But it click on basic auth button it gives error when control goes to alert , it showing this error 'chrome not reachable'

Comment: You can't test **Basic Authentication** in that fashion. Can you please have a look at the duplicate target if that solves your issue?

Comment: yes that working but I just want to test like above..because same code work in firefox but its not working in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome, alert blocks the event loop. You can work around that with:

```
driver.executeScript("window.alert = () => null");
```